# How can I transfer 12GB data to new server

Tags: linux, webserver, hosting, storage, file-transfer

I'm in the middle of changing our server. We bought server space at a different location and need to transfer all the content from our current server to the new one. I need to move 12GB over to the new server. What would be the most convenient, fastest, and easier way to transfer all that data to the new server... Doing a "physical" transfer is not an option.

I know is going to be a loooong procedure. I'm testing with some data and is taking a long long time.

I'm actually hosting about 10 websites on our local server so, I would like to move all that data to the new server... I do a backup of all the important files: /var/www, /home/, /var/lib/mysql, and others with tar -czf and it results into a 12GB tarball.

I don't have a big upload pipe so, I need to do a reliable transfer during off peak hours, 1am to 6am...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a good upload at our location... This is the main reason why we are changing servers and location.

Comment: Since the network is your bottleneck, using a higher compression level (or even a more agressive compression tool) might help.
For example: instead of `tar czf`, you could try `tar cf - yourfiles | gzip -9 - > result.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rsync

```
rsync -av --progress localpath usrname@remote:remotepath
```

I transfer 300GB data last night by this cmd.

Not need resume option, if interuppted, just run this cmd again. It will auto resume.

Actually, rsync is incremental.

Comment: Let me take a look at rsync... Thanks.

Comment: @Wilson You can also tell rsync to compress the transfer data as well as resume partial transfers in case the connection breaks in the middle of it.

Comment: I can't find the resume option

Comment: you can directly trasnfer files by RSYNC without tar,or you can user -z option to compress file by rsync itself,like @NikosC. said.

Answer (score 2):

If you have space on your drive, create a zip or rar archive with all you need. Move the archive to the root of one of your web sites. Use a "multi-threaded" HTTP download accelerator to get the file on the new server. Such tools creates multiple connections to the server, and should therefore improve you download speed noticably.

Make several smaller archives with your archive tool to get you started faster and better protection against transfer errors.

There are also FTP clients and servers with similar features, but I think the HTTP approach is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on a system with `tar`, you possibly also have `split` which can take your massive 12G file and turn it into a large number of smaller files.

Then transfer those "reliably" with ftp (do `md5sum` or `cksum` at both ends to check all files have duplicated correctly) and put them back together at the destination.

With pipelines, you shouldn't have to worry about any extra storage space required above and beyond the tarred-up file.

Comment: That works, of course, but note that rsync can do partial transfers and resumes (and compression), meaning there's no need to archive the files locally and then unpack at the destination server.

Comment: @Nikos, no doubt rsync is a better solution (which is why I +1'ed it), I'm just offering another if, for some bizarre reason, rsync is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `nc` or netcat. You can set it up to listen on your "server" and then provide the specifics from the machine with the 12 GB file. If you're after security though, `scp` is another consideration but it will be far slower than `nc` (or so I remember reading).

Comment: I was using scp but it takes a very long time.

Comment: Yeah, netcat will be faster, but it will still do it all in one shot instead of having to split files, compress them, transfer them, uncompress them and join them. *shrug*. On a local network I've transferred 5-7 GB files quickly with netcat. Of course I was confident in the security of the network, etc.